# Limiting Swift protocol with advanced where

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

I've run into a conceptual problem and am looking for advice.  I have a base class that defines all of the common properties a given object type:

```
class Widget {
    var id: Int
    var type: String
}
```

Many of these widgets share other properties and capabilities that are easily grouped.  The properties / capabilities fit nicely into protocols:

```
protocol WidgetryA {
    func widgetAFunc()
}

protocol WidgetryB {
    func widgetBFunc()
}
```

It's easy to extend the Widget class to conform to these various protocols:

```
extension Widget: WidgetryA {
    func widgetAFunc() { }
}
```

Note that Widgets may conform to multiple protocols.  No problem so far!  What I would like to do, and what I'm struggling with, is the following...  Widgets that have a certain Widget.type value should essentially be disallowed from conforming to a given Widgetry protocol.  So for example:

```
// this obviously doesn't work with where -- is there an alternative?
extension Widget: WidgetryA where Self.type == "foo" {
    func widgetAFunc() { }
}
```

Now I could do something gross and inelegant like guard()ing in protocol functions to prevent Widgets of the wrong Widget.type from making calls that they shouldn't.  I feel like associated types might provide a workable path to achieving what I want, but I am struggling coming up with a construct which works.  Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The `type` property of `Widget` is a stored property (and not e.g. an associated type). If your example would be legal (in some form), this would mean that the methods available to some given _type_ (which is essence defines the type) would be decided during _runtime_ (based on the _value_ of some property of the type), which is not possible in Swifts strong typing system. A common use is to limit extensions to types were some typelias (the `associatedtype`) fulfills some condition, but all such logic is resolved during compile time.

Comment: You cannot constrain a protocol based on a runtime attribute. If you need to do stringly typed differences, I would strongly recommend using enums.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an extension of the protocol:

```
extension WidgetryA where Self: Foo {
    func widgetAFunc() { }
}
```

so this `widgetAFunc` will be implemented only for classes that are of `Foo` type and conform to `WidgetryA` protocol. And of course you'd have to create subclasses of `Widget`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible as described in Swift for a couple reasons:

1. The Swift compiler doesn't know what the runtime values for the "type" property will be
2. Swift's generics and protocol extensions don't support excluding / disallowing / removing methods and implementations based on constraints, nor do generic constraints support matching types that are NOT something.

However, rather than using the type string, I would suggest making the Widget "type" a protocol itself, and then add the implementations via protocol extension to only instances that are Widgets that conform to the correct type protocol(s)

Comment: The explanation for 1 and 2 above are super clear.  Thanks.  Could you elaborate a bit on the final part of your answer however?  If I use a WidgetType protocol for Widget, I’m still not clear on how you would structure a Widgetry protocol, extend the WidgetType protocol or provide default protocol implementations for the Widget class to restrict a given protocol’s use.  There is some piece of the puzzle here that I’m still unable to see unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Restrict protocols to be adopted by a specific class like this :

```
My Protocol: MyViewController { 
  func myMethod()
}
```